# Non-recursive search on the file system

Tags: powershell

I want to search for files only under the parent directory and ignore all the other subd irectories with in the parent directory. However the script is searching for files in all the directories within the parent directory.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path "\\flamingdev\files\inbound\","*.csv" -Depth 0`
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`
| Add-Content -Path "\\flamingdev\files\input\files.txt"
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -File -Path "\\flamingdev\files\inbound\" -filter "*.csv" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
| Add-Content -Path "\\flamingdev\files\input\files.txt"`

Comment: I don't know how to mark your response as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all files, do not specify `-Recurse` or `-Depth`, just use `-Filter`:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path "\\flamingdev\files\inbound\" -Filter "*.csv"
```

By using `-Path "\\flamingdev\files\inbound\","*.csv"` you just specify two different locations for the search:

```
\\flamingdev\files\inbound\
*.csv
```